# Swift - Boolean property of SKSpritenode - is removed from parent?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

Is there a property of an `SKSpriteNode` which can be used to tell if it has been removed from the parent?

For example,

```
self.addChild(sprite)
print(sprite.isRemoved) //prints false

sprite.removeFromParent()
print(sprite.isRemoved) //prints true
```

Answer (score 3):

All SKNode's have a parent property which is an optional. So you can see if the node has a parent.

```
if sprite.parent == nil {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the `parent` attribute of the `SKNode` is `nil`.

```
if sprite.parent == nil {
    print("sprite has been removed from the parent")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You check write your function or variable like this using guard statement.

```
var isRemoved: Bool {
  guard let parent = sprite.parent else {return true}
  return false
}
```

> And you can check this isRemoved variable in your code whether it has been removed from the parent or not.